# How to search the web for JavaScript using Google, or other crawler?

Tags: google-search

I know you can search Google for specific filetypes, so you can do `filetype:js someCode`

However, Google doesn't seem to index JavaScript, or at least these results just seem to be HTML pages with a .js suffix in the URL.

I find it unlikely that Google ever discards or ignores any data, so perhaps there is some way to search within indexed JavaScript files?

Or are other services out there that index JavaScript?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7778034/198836) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Great, thanks! And to think I deliberately came to webapps to avoid my question being closed :D